# Mongoose pre save middleware is not triggering/saving hashed passwords to db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to pre save and hash password with bcrypt in mongoose in my next.js project, but password still unhashed. i tryed every link in stackoverflow and didnt solve it, the password still saved unHashed.
mongoose version: 6.9.1

this is my users.model file:

```
import {
  models,
  model,
  Schema,
} from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  displayName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
  },
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('Pre-Save Hash has fired.');
  let user = this;
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

const UserModel = models.Users || model('Users', UserSchema, 'users');

export default UserModel;
```

this is my adding function file:

```
import dbConnect from '@/utils/mongodb';
import UserModel from '@/models/user.model';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { MongoError } from 'mongodb';
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  // const { email, password } = req.query;
  try {
    dbConnect();
    const query = req.body;
    const newUser = new UserModel(query);
    const addedUser= await newUser.save(function (err: MongoError) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    });
    res.status(200).json(addedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
}
```

i cant see the 'Pre-Save Hash has fired.' in my console also..

Comment: do you get this logged :`console.log('Pre-Save Hash has fired.');`

Comment: no, i didnt get..the pre save is not triggered

Comment: is this the one you want to save `const { email, password } = req.query`

Comment: no, it's commented. the want i want to save is res.bodyobject, that has a password key

Comment: r u also passing `displayName` which is required in the schema?

Comment: is, my req.body keys are: displayName, password, email, role - all are strings, and all saved to db also, but pre save not triggered

Comment: can you create a reproducible repo. this seems very odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You need to add user.isModified("password")
userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  var user = this;
  if (user.isModified("password")) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_I, (err, salt) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};



// to make register end point
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import User from "../../../models/User";

const dbConnect = async () => {
  mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Connected to mongoDb");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    await dbConnect();
    const query = req.body;
    const newUser = new User(query);
    await newUser.save(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(result);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all.
The problem was in my dbconnect file!